# JQ radio button value issue

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a form with three sets of radio buttons. Each radio button has a value ranging from 0 to 3. I then have some JS/JQ which looks through which button is checked, takes the value, adds it all together and then uses that number to post a specific response. My problem is that I can't seem to get the selection of the value right. Help!

```
<input type="radio" name="answer-q1" value="0"><span class="answer-text">Strongly Disagree</span>

var totalPoints = 0;
var q1 = $('input:radio[name=answer-q1]:checked').find(':value').val();
var q2 = $('input:radio[name=answer-q2]:checked').find(':value').val();
var q3 = $('input:radio[name=answer-q3]:checked').find(':value').val();
totalPoints = q1 + q2 + q3;
```

I've tried several different things but no dice. I'm sure the answer is just starring me in the face but I'm not seeing it. If anyone has any advice I would be really grateful. Thanks.

I've added the rest of my JS/JQ below:

```
 var totalPoints = 0;
var q1 = $('input[name=answer-q1]:checked', '#module5').val();
var q2 = $('input[name=answer-q2]:checked', '#module5').val();
var q3 = $('input[name=answer-q3]:checked', '#module5').val();
totalPoints = q1 + q2 + q3;
$("button").on('submit', function(e) {
    if (totalPoints >= 0 && totalPoints <= 4) {
        $('.content').html('<p>text goes here</p>');
    } else if (totalPoints >= 5 && totalPoints <= 9) {
        $('.content').html('<p>text goes here</p>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems in your code.

1. The variables should be sitting inside your submit function. And your submit function is looking for a `form` not a `button`, so your selector should be your form's id`$("#module5")` your JS should be like this"

   ```
   <script>
       var totalPoints = 0;
       $("#module5").on('submit', function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var q1 = parseInt($('input:radio[name=answer-q1]:checked').val());
           var q2 = parseInt($('input:radio[name=answer-q2]:checked').val());
           var q3 = parseInt($('input:radio[name=answer-q3]:checked').val());
           totalPoints = q1 + q2 + q3;
           if (totalPoints >= 0 && totalPoints <= 4) {
               $('.content').html('<p>Text goes here.</p>');
           } else if (totalPoints >= 5 && totalPoints <= 9) {
               $('.content').html('<p>Text goes here.</p>');
           }
       });
   </script>
   ```
2. Your HTML's form submit button should be like this (notice the `type="submit"`)

   ```
   <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit Answer">
   ```

Comment: Oh man. Thank you @CodeGodie. That worked. I'm gonna look over what you did more closely so I never make the same mistakes again. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this no need to use `.find(':value')`[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/khezcp4x/1/) check the demo

```
$(".submit").click(function(){

var totalPoints = 0;
var q1 = parseInt($('input:radio[name=answer-q1]:checked').val());
var q2 = parseInt($('input:radio[name=answer-q2]:checked').val());
var q3 = parseInt($('input:radio[name=answer-q3]:checked').val());
totalPoints = q1 + q2 + q3;

    alert(totalPoints);
    if (totalPoints >= 0 && totalPoints <= 4) {
        $('.content').html('<p>Text goes here.</p>');
    } else if (totalPoints >= 5 && totalPoints <= 9) {
        $('.content').html('<p>Text goes here.</p>');
    }
});
```

Comment: that didn't seem to work either. I wonder if something is off about the rest of my code?

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     $( "#check" ).click(function() {
         var v1=parseInt($("input[name=answer-q1]:checked").val());
         var v2=parseInt($("input[name=answer-q2]:checked").val());
         var v3=parseInt($("input[name=answer-q3]:checked").val());
         var ans=v1+v2+v3;
 alert(ans);

     });
    });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
Value1
<input type="radio"  name="answer-q1" value="1">1
<input type="radio"  name="answer-q1" value="2">2
<input type="radio"  name="answer-q1" value="3">3<br>
Value2
<input type="radio" name="answer-q2" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="answer-q2" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="answer-q2" value="3">3<br>

Value3
<input type="radio" name="answer-q3" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="answer-q3" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="answer-q3" value="3">3<br>
<button id="check">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```